# creating custom module in ejabberd

Tags: erlang

I have created custom module in ejabberd. Main problem is that if i want to add both mysql and mnesia support in start(HOST) -> function

```
IQDisc = gen_mod:get_opt(iqdisc, Opts, fun gen_iq_handler:check_type/1,
    one_queue),
  Mod = gen_mod:db_mod(Host, Opts, ?MODULE),
  Mod:init(Host, Opts)
```

after restarting ejabberd it gives me critical error:

```
14:05:26.453 [critical] Problem starting the module mod_conversation for host <<"localhost">> 
 options: []
 error: undef
[{mod_conversation_undefined,init,[<<"localhost">>,[]],[]},
 {mod_conversation,start,2,[{file,"src/mod_conversation.erl"},{line,30}]},
 {gen_mod,start_module,3,[{file,"src/gen_mod.erl"},{line,154}]},
 {lists,foreach,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1337}]},
 {ejabberd_app,start,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_app.erl"},{line,77}]},
 {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                     [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,273}]}]
14:05:26.453 [critical] ejabberd initialization was aborted because a module start failed.

Crash dump is being written to: //var/log/ejabberd/erl_crash_20170115-140523.dump...done
Problem starting the module mod_conversation for host <<"localhost">> 
 options: []
 error: undef
[{mod_conversation_undefined,init,[<<"localhost">>,[]],[]},
 {mod_conversation,start,2,[{file,"src/mo
```

I already add new module in ejabberd configuration file. if i remove

```
Mod = gen_mod:db_mod(Host, Opts, ?MODULE),
Mod:init(Host, Opts)]
```

my module starts successfully. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `Mod` variable contents seems to be `mod_conversation_undefined`. Look why `gen_mod:db_mod/3` returns `mod_conversation_undefined`.

Comment: so ejabberd does not guess which database used by this module, by the way my default db_type is sql also there is same code in other ejabberd modules, so i don't get why Mod variable is undefined

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use database backends, you should create mod_conversation_$BACKEND modules, e.g. mod_conversation_mnesia, mod_conversation_sql, etc.
You should also add 'db_type' option to mod_opt_type/1 callback of your module (otherwise any backends will be ignored and you will get mod_conversation_undefined). You can take a look how it's done in other modules, for example in simple ones, like mod_private.